# SKPaymentTransaction transactionIdentifier doesn't match my receipt

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

When I've purchased a (free) non-consumable in-app 'pack', and then cleaned the app off the device and re-installed it, a subsequent 'buy' request of the 'pack' causes the app store to prompt the user to download again, after saying that they've already bought it - fantastic. Just what I want.

But when I come to validate the incoming payment's transactionID within the receipt, the incoming SKPaymentTransactionID.transactionIdentifier doesn't match anything in the receipt. It does however match perfectly for consumables - probably because they are 'new' purchases?

Currently the restore/download process works fine, but my validation of transactionID in the receipt fails because no new transaction ID is issued - the date of the transaction has been modified.

Question: Should it? Or is the mistake I'm making to call `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];` on something the user has already bought, and should I be reading the receipt first and updating my UI so that they only get the option to restore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `originalTransaction` object of the incoming `SKPaymentTransaction`, and compare against that instead.